# list large numbers of items in dropdown asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have currently implemented a drop-down which displays all the products name from database. On selection of product name from drop down my edit product form will get populated and user can update selected record successfully.

Now my problem is that i have 5000 products in my database.In this case its very difficult for end user to select particular product in drop-down and also populating drop down with large number of records server side takes more time.

What approach should i use to make selection user friendly.Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated

Thanks!!!!

Comment: if your products are divided into catogories you can create seperate combo to display catogory and then display products from only that selected category

Comment: thanks for reply sudhakar. my products in table are not associated with any category.I just have 5000 rows in table.

Comment: @Dave if your rows has some can-categorized elements (suppose your rows are about real estate properties..As normally these properties can categorized with their room counts (2+1, 3+1, dublex etc) then you can follow Sudhakar's way..

Comment: Did my solution work out for you?

Comment: @akash.. Am Not getting ideas on how to proceed.. I am. thinking to implement jquery datable.. Since I am using. Net 3.5..  am feeling difficultly in it also as i am not able to find suitable example.. Thanks for your answer . I dont think combo box will suit with my interface of editing form. Thats where am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an editable combo box with auto complete feature and load the data depending on user input. Refer this: http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx

This way you dont need to worry about the amount of data, it gets filtered as the user inputs some string.

Comment: I agree with Aakash, I would also use auto-complete to solve this problem. An alternative to the the AjaxControlToolKit is to use jQuery. You will need to write a simple web service in either instance to fill the auto-complete.